# React+Redux обновление стора

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Как отследить изменение стора в Redux? В интеренете нашел что используется метод componentWillReceiveProps. Я пытаюсь в нем вызвать метод который подгружает список данных, но при этом стор опять обновляется, и получается что он зацикливатеся

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('props', this.props.active)
    console.log('nextProps', nextProps.active)
    this.props.getCustomersListAction({ 
        type: this.props.type, 
        project: this.props.project, 
        active: nextProps.active 
   })
}
```

в данном случае меня интересует только параметр active, как понять что он поменялся?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux), библиотека предоставляет функцию `connect`, которая позволяет связать компонент с redux store.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    render() { 
        const {active} = this.props;
        return ...
    }
}

export default connect(
    (state) => ({active: state.active})
)(MyComponent)
```

`connect` принимает 2 функции, первая нужна для передачи стейта в компонент из стораджа,  вторая для передачи экшен криэйторов.
Компонент будет обновляться каждый раз когда данные переданные через `connect` будут менятся

Comment: Для решения задачи *отследить* изменения можно использовать redux-logger - https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger

Comment: Так я и делаю, но вопрос в том как по умному отслеживать изменения конкретных полей. допустим у меня будет 5 или 6 полей при изенении которых мне надо обновлять список

Comment: @JonnyManowar, просто сравните this.props и nextprops по тем полям которые нужно. И вызывайте action после проверки

Comment: Вообще, в 99% случаев ничего отслеживать не надо - реакт делает всё сам, если пропсы так или иначе транслируются в рендер()